# Однородные члены предложения

Tags: синтаксис

"В ней он хочет выразить не только чувства, но и всю любовь к родному краю, к неброской прелести русской природы".

Я составил схему предложения так: не только О, но и  О О, О. В схеме от слова "любовь" я провел к словам "к краю", "к прелести природы" стрелки.

Учитель зачеркнула последний кружочек со словом "прелести". И получилось вот что: не только О, но и О, О. (здесь все о.ч. явл-ся дополнениями).

Какая схема правильная?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"В ней он хочет выразить не только чувства, но и всю любовь к родному краю, к неброской прелести русской природы". Здесь два ряда однородных членов - однородные дополнения (не только чувства, но и любовь) и однородные определения (любовь какая? - к краю, к прелести).

Можно указать в схеме один ряд с дополнениями, что учительница и хотела сделать:

1) если нужно указать однородные дополнения - [не только О, но и О ];

2) если указывать два ряда однородных членов, будет громоздкая схема: [-   =   не только Θ, но и Θ О,О ] (в кружочках волнистая линия).

Может, она хотела убрать оба кружочка-определения, а убрала только один.

Comment: Она после,но и О вставила запятую .

Comment: Тогда я её не понимаю